# How get syslogd running on DDEV

Tags: ddev

I installed Drupal syslog module and I want to make sure that syslog configuration is working correctly. But checking inside the web container, I don't know if syslogd is running, and I haven't found where the logs might be.

Answer (score 6):

As Randy said, you can add the syslog daemon as a post-start hook in your *config.yaml*. We use it as follows:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec: sudo syslogd
    - exec: printf "\n\n#Drupal logs\n#local0.* /var/log/drupal.log\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/syslog.conf
```

This starts *syslogd* and configures it to write everything in facility (I guess its called like that) "local0.*" to */var/log/drupal.log*.
To see what's in there, simply ssh into DDEV (`ddev ssh`) and run `tail -f /var/log/syslog`.

After enabling the syslog module you need to go to *admin/config/development/logging* and select "LOG_LOCAL0" as syslog facility and set a syslog format.

Answer (score 3):

1. You have to install syslogd in your web container by adding `webimage_extra_packages: [inetutils-syslogd]` to your config.yaml and then restart. This will add the necessary package.
2. After starting your project, you should `ddev ssh` and run `syslogd`. That will manually start syslogd. If you want this to always start up, you can add running syslogd to a post-start exec hook.
3. The logs from syslogd go into /var/log/syslog

It probably makes more sense to use a different syslogd server, so you could use one of the many syslog images on hub.docker.com as a third-party service in ddev, or you could run syslogd on your workstation, or you could also use something like https://www.papertrail.com/

Comment: Thank Randy, I got  the logs to show up. For some reason I needed to set `local0.* /var/log/drupal.log`
into `/etc/syslog.conf` then i ran `syslogd` for restart the service.

Comment: Just so you know, your edits to /etc/syslog.conf won't survive a `ddev restart`, but since you're just kicking the tires, that should be OK. You could add a permanent overwrite of syslog.conf with .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile, but that's probably more than you want right now.